# Want to Hide the UIbutton when user types some textfiled and press return key

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

[image: This image has , buttons and text filed , if type some text and hit return key in keyboard all the created uibutton should get disable]I have created a `UIButton` based on anarray count. The user can type some text in a field, then press the next button to go to the next page, or (s)he can touch any of the created buttons to go to next page.

What I would like to do here is, if the user types some text and presses the return key, then I want to hide the all the created `UIButtons`, and secondly, if the user touches any button, the textfield should hide. How can I do this?

This is my code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.txt_Comments setDelegate:self];

    [self.txt_Comments addTarget:self
                          action:@selector(textFieldDidChange)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange{
    if (self.txt_Comments.text.length == 0) {
        [self.word setEnabled:YES];
        [self.txt_Comments setEnabled:NO]; 
    }
    else {   
        [self.word setEnabled:NO];
        [self.txt_Comments setEnabled:YES];

        UIBarButtonItem *NextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Next"
                                       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                       target:self 
                                       action:@selector(next_ButtonTapped:)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = NextButton; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: did u implement the text field delegate mthods ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not here to write your code. Setting visibility of UI elements is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

comapare textfield and hide button.

Comment: Actually use can do either type text in textfield or touch a button to move to next page .if user type text field in want to disable the all created uibutton ,or else if user press the button then i want to hide the textfiled , Please help me to do this

Comment: i am really confuse what u try to saying.